# Getting last position in master-file-log (MySQL replication)?

Tags: mysql, replication, database-replication, multi-master-replication

How could I retrieve last position in master's log-bin? For example when I write `CHANGE MASTER TO...` I can't see master's status so I don't know the master-file-pos...

Answer (score 1):

On your master machine in mysql type:

```
SHOW MASTER STATUS;

mysql> SHOW MASTER STATUS;
+---------------+----------+--------------+------------------+
| File          | Position | Binlog_Do_DB | Binlog_Ignore_DB |
+---------------+----------+--------------+------------------+
| mysql-bin.003 | 73       | test         | manual,mysql     |
+---------------+----------+--------------+------------------+
```

Comment: Well. I'm trying to do this: http://www.onlamp.com/2006/04/20/advanced-mysql-replication.html
When procedure calls "CHANGE MASTER TO..." it doesn't know right position of the new master's master-log-pos.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I am not sure what you exactly want to achive, but do a `SHOW SLAVE STATUS;` and look there for Exec_Master_Log_Pos, this will give you the last position until which the slave SQL thread has executed the events from the masters binary log.

For additional information refer to the docs you can find here: [SHOW SLAVE STATUS Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/show-slave-status.html)